# What is the weight of walk and the intuition behind Prune and Enrichment sampling?

Tags: sampling, random-walk

For context, I am reading this document: https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/t.prellberg/papers/pub084pre.pdf.

I am on the section of pruned and enrichment sampling of a random walk. The document neatly lays out a genealogy of random walk methods. They first explain simple random walks, biased random walks (one direction is globally biased by probability $p$), uniform sampled walks (walk is locally biased as a  function of steps taken $n$ and location $k$). So far this makes sense.

I do not understand the motivation behind Pruned and Enriched Smapling (PERM). To be specific, I am not sure what pruning and enriching is doing.

Let's say I do a simple walk of $n_1$ steps and land at position $k_1$. I compute weight of walk as $w$. Seeing that $R = w/W < 1$, I must prune my walk. If $R>1$, I must enrich my walk.

If $R<1$, I have to continue growing the walk with probability $R$ and set weight $w$ to $W$, and stop growing with probability $1-R$. Does this mean I keep adding another step to my walk with probability $R$? Furthermore, what is the weight of a simple walk run for $n$ steps with length $k$? In the document, $P_{n,k} = 1/2^n {{n}\choose{k}}$, so is the weight of the walk simple $1/P_{n,k}$?

If $R>1$, we have to make parallel copies of the walk, and continue growing them. Isn't running parallel simulation expensive?

I understand the implementation of this, but I do not get why somebody would come up with this. Why is this method an improvement on uniform sampling and locally biasing the walk and keeping track of this bias?